# How do I run a Ipython cell from command line in the background?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ipython

I'm trying to run a big algorithm (ML) that takes about 4 hours in IPython. The problem is that my local CPU does not support this and hence I have to use AWS. My network isn't very stable and there are frequent disconnects from the server. So, my question is:

How can I run a cell from commandline (ssh) with nohup option so that it will continue running even after disconnecting from the IPYthon server? And how do I go back and fetch the results and kill the process at the end of it?

Comment: read the manpage for screen https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html

Comment: @at0mzk screen helps me reattach and detach from IPYthon shell, but the cell still needs to be run interactively, i.e. browser needs to be connected to the server....